# Print out the alphabet using for loop and setw

Tags: c++

When I compile my program, run it and enter values I will get a rather strange and unexpected output:

So if I enter:

```
Enter width and height: 9 5
Enter characters: X O
1  XOXOXOXOX
2  OXOXOXOXO
3  XOXOXOXOX
4  OXOXOXOXO
5  XOXOXOXOX
A   BCDEFGHI
```

When it's supposed to be:

```
Enter width and height: 9 5
Enter characters: X O
1  XOXOXOXOX
2  OXOXOXOXO
3  XOXOXOXOX
4  OXOXOXOXO
5  XOXOXOXOX
   ABCDEFGHI
```

When do my `void print_alphabet` in another program it will work out just fine so I don't know the problem. I believe it has something to do with my other function but I can not seem to get it to work. Why does it act that way? Why does it print out A and then it does setw and prints out the rest?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_chess_board (int const height,
                        int const width,
                        char const char_1,
                        char const char_2)
{
    
    int index {};
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
    {
        if (i%2)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index = 1;
        }
        
        cout << left << setw(3) << i;
        
        for (int j {}; j < width; ++j)
        {
    
           
          if (++index%2 == 0)
          {
              cout << char_2;
          }
          
          else
          {
              cout << char_1;
          }
        }
        
        cout << endl;
    }
    

   
}

void print_alphabet (int const width)
{
  
  cout << setfill(' ') << setw(4);

    for (int i {}; i < width; ++i)
    {
        cout << char('A' + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int width {};
    int height {};
    char char_1 {};
    char char_2 {};
    
    cout << "Enter width and height: ";
    cin >> width >> height;
    
    cout << "Enter characters: ";
    cin >> char_1 >> char_2;
   
    print_chess_board(height,width,char_1,char_2);
    print_alphabet(width);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `std::cout << std::string(4, ' ');`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
cout << setfill(' ') << setw(4);
```

to

```
cout << right << setfill(' ') << setw(4);
```